# Deleting Row with PyMYSQL

Tags: python, sql, pymysql

I'm trying to delete rows in 2 tables (actor and characters) when the actor is in less episodes that numEpisodes, a parameter passed in. I've got the following code:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM actor WHERE numEpisodes < %s",num_episodes);
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM characters WHERE actorID IN (SELECT actorID FROM actor WHERE numEpisodes < %s",num_episodes);
connection.commit()
```

I keep getting a 1064 syntax error but I do not see what is wrong, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Your  "IN (" needs a matching ")".  FYI if you google it there are online MySQL syntax checkers

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a close paren, and the parameters passed to the `execute` function must be an iterable, like a tuple. However,  your logic is backwards.  After you delete from `actor`, there will no longer BE any records for that `SELECT` to return.

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM characters WHERE actorID IN (SELECT actorID FROM actor WHERE numEpisodes < %s)",(num_episodesm));
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM actor WHERE numEpisodes < %s", (num_episodesm));
connection.commit()
```